# how to decrypt xml elements stored after encryption

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption

I am trying to encrypt XML elements before saving.

Below is the code to get values and save.

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.Load("../../Info.xml");
 XmlElement ParentElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Details");
 XmlElement userID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ID");
 userID.InnerText = strName;
 XmlElement userPwd = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Pwd");
 userPwd.InnerText = strPwd;
 XmlElement startDate = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Start");
 startDate.InnerText = dtStart.ToString();
 XmlElement expiryDate = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Expiry");
 expiryDate.InnerText = dtExpiry.ToString();
 ParentElement.AppendChild(userID);
 ParentElement.AppendChild(userPwd);
 ParentElement.AppendChild(startDate);
 ParentElement.AppendChild(expiryDate);
 xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ParentElement);
 xmlDoc.Save("../../Info.xml");
```

Now I have a private string (code shown below) which can encrypt the inner xml contents before save

```
 private string Encrypt(string clearText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

I am passing the innerxml contents(shown below) and `clearText` string encrypts the contents.

```
string str = Encrypt(xmlUserDoc.InnerXml);
File.WriteAllText("../../Info.xml", str);
```

Now I am able to save the encrypted contents.

Now how can I decrypt and load the xml doc into readable format?

Comment: Do you want to encrypt whole XML file or only contents? Depending upon the data, it may impact the performance. How about encrypting only sensitive data like "Pwd"? Otherwise, you can save the contents (clearText) in a file. And at the time of reading it, decrypt and parse again.

Comment: @Anand - I need to encrypt the whole file means whenever I add new contents it needs to be encrypted.

Comment: You will need to use the same EncryptionKey to decrypt the data.

Comment: @Anand - how can I decrypt the file and load them in page load in this line ` XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("../../Info.xml"). My question is how to pass the contents to decrypt and that's where I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

You currently *encrypt* your string with the following steps:

1. Encode string to Unicode
2. Encrypt Unicode Byte array
3. Convert Encrypted Byte array to Base64

To *decrypt* it, you simply have to reverse the order:

1. Convert Base64 to Byte array
2. Decrypt Byte array
3. Decode Unicode Byte array to string

```cs
private string Decrypt(string encrypted)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);

    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";

    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, 
          new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, 
              encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
                cs.CopyTo(buffer);

                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I decrypt the file and load them in page load in this line ` XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("../../Info.xml"). My question is how to pass the contents to decrypt and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Learner You could load the encrypted file with `File.ReadAllText` (or something like that), decrypt it and load the XDocument with `XDocument.Parse` instead of `Load`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code as encrypt with two changes

1. while creating byte array
2. Instead of CreateEncryptor use CreateDecryptor

Try following

```
public static string Decrypt(string sEncryptedText)
     {
         string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
         byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sEncryptedText);
         using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
         {
             Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new
                 Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
             encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
             encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
             using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                 {
                     cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                     cs.Close();
                 }
                 sEncryptedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
             }
         }
         return sEncryptedText;
     }
```